# delete numbers from a column consisting characters and numbers in bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, printf

I have the following input file

```
H1
C1
C2
C3
H2
C4
.
.
.
```

I would like to obtain the following output format only with the characters and not the numbers

```
H
C
C
C
H
C
.
.
.
```

Comment: `tr -d '[:digit:]' < input.file`

Comment: if you just need the first character of each line, you can also use `cut -c1 ip.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tr`

```
tr -d '0-9' < file
```

`tr -d` will delete all characters from the given character set (here: `[0-9]`).

Comment: fyi, at least on Ubuntu, `tr` doesn't need `[]` to define a range.. `tr -d '[0-9]'` would delete the `[]` characters too..

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` to get a preview:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g' file
```

or

```
sed -i 's/[[:digit:]]//g' file
```

to do it in-place, editing the file itself.